# If the attribute has "No" or not filled out, then do not display for bundled product

Tags: admin, adminhtml, javascript, css, grouped-products

I'm currently displaying a block that has a custom attribute for simple products. But, I don't want to display it for grouped products, only for simple products.

In `Manage Products > Custom Attribute` I set everything to be blank for just that attribute. I would like Magento to not show the custom attribute tab if the setting is blank or `0`.

Perhaps it could be an If statement and hook a display none tag to it? Here is the line I'm looking at that might be useful

```
<?php if ($attributeValue === 'No' || strpos($_data['code'], '(dv)')) continue; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
if (!$product->getAttributeText('attribute_name') ||
    $product->getAttributeText('attribute_name') == Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No')
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout file `catalog.xml` provides you with custom handles for every type of product type.

The one you're looking for is `PRODUCT_TYPE_simple`. This should allow you to do something like

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="yourcustom/block" name="custom_attributes" template="yourcustom/block.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

and call that block from the `catalog/product/view.phtml` or where ever you want to call it from.

Comment: great I think this is the way to go, how can I call the block now once I've added it in the catalog.xml?

Comment: you can call the block by adding `echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_attributes');` in the reference block

Comment: Still no luck. I added this to catalog.xml

  <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="custom_attributes" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>

and then called teh block with the getChildHtml on the catalog.phtml

Comment: I'm not familiar with that phtml but find the <block> tag that uses that file as as a template and then use it's name as the name for the <reference> block

Comment: this is from the default layout... all I did was change default.phtml to simple.phtml

Comment: <PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>

Comment: sorry I'n not too sure whats going wrong. Perhaps edit your question to add your new code or pose another question.